# sparql using wikiPageRedirects

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am using sparql to find a location of entity. I have urls from dbpedia-spootlight and want to find location for them. So the query I am using is:

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
SELECT DISTINCT * 
WHERE { ?uri rdfs:label ?label . 
OPTIONAL { ?uri geo:lat ?lat . ?uri geo:long ?long } . 
OPTIONAL { ?uri dbpedia-owl:country ?dbpediaContry . ?dbpediaContry dbpprop:cctld ?ccTLD } . 
FILTER (?uri = <URL>  && lang(?label) = "en" ) }
```

and it was fine until I have got this url: http://dbpedia.org/resource/Valencia,_Spain .
It has wikiPageRedirects to http://dbpedia.org/resource/Valencia and no other data.
I have got lost how could i build query to check cases with redirects.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Btw your use of prefixes and prefixed names is very inconsistent, as written your query really should be rejected as invalid because you've used undefined prefixes

Comment: yeah that's true. anyway I still play with it so didn´t really care about that. anyway it is good point. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the first part of your query to use a `UNION` e.g.

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#> 
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT DISTINCT * 
WHERE
{ 
  { 
    ?uri rdfs:label ?label . 
  } 
  UNION 
  { 
    [] dbo:wikiPageRedirects ?uri .
    ?uri rdfs:label ?label .
  }
  OPTIONAL 
  { 
    ?uri geo:lat ?lat ;
         geo:long ?long 
  }
  OPTIONAL 
  {
    ?uri dbo:country ?dbpediaContry . 
    ?dbpediaContry dbp:cctld ?ccTLD 
  }
  FILTER (SAMETERM(?uri, <URL>)  && lang(?label) = "en" ) 
}
```

The `UNION` allow you to find things that have a URI and those that have a URI via a redirect before then applying the rest of your query.  Note I also changed your `FILTER` to use `SAMETERM()` which should make the query faster.

In general if you have this kind of query where you are doing that sort of a `FILTER` to set a constant I would strongly suggest just replacing all uses of the `?uri` variable with `<URL>` instead which should see much better performance

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have found a solution but I don´t think it is perfect.
I added additional columns:

```
...
OPTIONAL { ?uri  dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects ?red } .
OPTIONAL { ?red geo:lat ?rlat . ?red geo:long ?rlong } 
...
```

but now I have 2 columns more to check in response.

Another way I was trying is:

```
...
OPTIONAL { ?uri  dbpedia-owl:wikiPageRedirects ?red } .
{?uri geo:lat ?lat . ?uri geo:long ?long}  UNION  { ?red geo:lat ?lat . ?red geo:long ?long }
...
```

but then i have any answer if entity doesn´t have geo:long & geo:lat

So, anybody knows better solution?